# Running Nested Tests with CTest

Tags: unit-testing, cmake, ctest

I have a small, but non-trivial project, which for architectural reasons is built as three separete projects, they are inter-dependent, so unless I'm particularly focused, or improving test-coverage having spotted a hole, it makes sense for me to work from the proejct root.

The layout is as such:

```
/CMakeLists.txt
/build/
/src/command-line-application/
/src/command-line-application/CMakeLists.txt
/src/command-line-application/build/
/src/command-line-application/src/
/src/command-line-application/tests/
/src/command-line-application/include/
/src/vlc-plugin/
/src/vlc-plugin/src/
/src/libmyproject/
/src/libmyproject/CMakeLists.txt
/src/libmyproject/build/
/src/libmyproject/src/
/src/libmyproject/tests/
/src/libmyproject/include/
/src/libmyotherproject/
/src/libmyotherproject/CMakeLists.txt
/src/libmyotherproject/build/
/src/libmyotherproject/src/
/src/libmyotherproject/tests/
/src/libmyotherproject/include/
```

A word on the architecture, `libmyproject` is the real meat of my application, it's built this way because a CLI is a horrible way to ship code to end-users, as a library, it is also used from C# and Objective-C applications. (and all that works as expected)

The `libmyotherproject` is some platform specific support code, not directly connected to `libmyproject`, it has a few unit tests.

The `vlc-plugin` isn't important here, except to show that not everything in `/src/*/` has unit tests.

My workflow is typically to hack on the CLI app until something useful crops up, and then refactor it into the library, and make sure it's portable.

When I'm working in `/src/*/build/`, typically running `cmake ../ && make && ctest --output-on-failure`, everything works.

When I'm working in `/build`, and run `cmake`, the individual components are built correctly (using `add_subdirectories()`) from CMake, but `CTest` does not recursively find the tests.

The documentation for `CTest` is a little unhelpful in what you should do:

```
USAGE
         ctest [options]

DESCRIPTION
       The  "ctest"  executable is the CMake test driver program.  CMake-generated build trees created for
       projects that use the ENABLE_TESTING and ADD_TEST commands have testing support.  This program will
       run the tests and report results.
```

I would have expected since the `ADD_TEST()` calls live in `/src/libmyotherproject/tests/CMakeLists.txt`, that they would be run? (They are at least compiled when I run `cmake` from `/build/`)

I hope I have been able to provide enough informaton, thank you.

Comment: Do you have an `enable_testing()` call in the outermost CMakeLists.txt?

Comment: `enable_testing()` is in the `/src/libmyproject/CMakeLists.txt` along with a further `add_subdirectory('tests')`, which correctly (when in `/src/libmyproject/build`) compiles, and (with `ctest`) runs the tests. Adding `enable_testing()` to the top `CMakeLists.txt` doesn't change anything. The `CMakeLists.txt` in `/src/libmyproject/tests/` includes the `add_test()` call itself.

Comment: Perhaps you called enable_testing() after all your add_subdirectory() calls? It should work if you do it before the add_subdirectory calls. Prefer "include(CTest)" though, as in my answer, which calls enable_testing() for you.

Answer (score 5):

Put

```
include(CTest)
```

in your top level CMakeLists.txt file before you make any add_subdirectory calls.

That will call enable_testing for you, and also set things up if you ever want to run a ctest dashboard script on the project to send results to a CDash server.